# Derived type cannot be implicitly converted to base interface

Tags: .net-3.5, inheritance, interface, c#-3.0

```
interface IModel {}

class MyModel : IModel {}

interface IRepo<T>
    where T: IModel { }

class Repo : IRepo<MyModel> { }

//EDIT: A smaller example
IRepo<IModel> repo = new Repo(); // Cannot implicitly convert.. An explicit convertion exists. Missing cast?

// Old example:
/*
The type 'Repo' cannot be used as type parameter 'C' in the generic type or method.
'Castle.MicroKernel.Registration.ComponentRegistration<S>.ImplementedBy<C>()'.
==> There is no implicit reference conversion from 'Repo' to 'IRepo<IModel>'.
*/
container.Register(
    Component.For<IRepo<IModel>>()
   .ImplementedBy<Repo>());
```

But Repo is derived from IRepo, and MyModel is derived from IModel. Why doesn't this work?

I tried adding an implicit operator on Repo, but it's not allowed to convert between interfaces..

Is this solved by the co/contra varience thing from c#4 (No, I don't have a clue what I'm talking about :) )?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your intuition was right.  This is a covariance issue.  You see, `IRepo<IModel>` and `IRepo<MyModel>` are not the same.

To allow for covariant types, you can fix it with the `out` modifier in C# 4:

```
interface IRepo<out T> where T: IModel {}
```

If you are not on C# 4 yet, you will need to tighten your usage:

```
IRepo<MyModel> repo = new Repo();
```

Answer (score 3):

You are correct. It does not work because of Co/Contravariance. It is supposed to work in C# 4 (I didn´t test it because I never needed such a thing :P).

A good explanation on how it works can be found here: [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/csharpfaq/covariance-and-contravariance-faq)

Comment: It doesn't work out of the box in C# 4.  The `IRepo` interface needs to be modified with the covariance modifier: `out`.